# Rviz middle button zooming instead of move x/y

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm playing around with Rviz plotting a point cloud.  Trying to move the x/y with middle click, but it's zooming instead.  Left button behavior is correct (rotate).  Right button behavior also correct (zooming).  So, center and right buttons both zoom and I can't move the scene.

I'm using a Thinkpad with 3 buttons.  Center button has default Linux paste functionality, and scrolling with the trackpoint.

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328924/rviz-middle-button-zooming-instead-of-move-x/y/) by [thinkpadfanboy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40450/thinkpadfanboy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use the alternative: Shift+Left Mouse Click.

This does not exactly solve the behavior, but it's easier than trying to fix the machine.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2019-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinkpadfanboy](https://answers.ros.org/users/40450/thinkpadfanboy/) on 2019-07-18**:
That works.  Thanks!

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2019-07-19**:
In that case please accept the answer so this question is removed from the "Unanswered" section